# Is there a solution for this button problem?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am building up my skills by designing a mini web pag
so I started the navigation bar .

The button "Template" is supposed to change the view of the  and display the lists but when I click it nothing happens.

Can anyone help me ?

The code:

html:

```
   <div class="menu-toggle">
            <h1 id="logo">PROTOCOL</h1>
            <li class="right table" id="table"><a class="list template" href="#template" >&#9776;</a></li>

            <span class="bar"></span>

            <span class="bar"></span>

            <span class="bar"></span>

        </div>




        <ul id="navigate" class="navigate">

            <li><a class="list home" href="#home"> Home</a></li>


            <li><a class="list" href="#conntacting">Contact us</a></li>





            <li class="right"><a class="list sign-up" href="#signing">Sign up</a></li>

            <li class="right"><a class="list" href="#logging">Log in</a></li>

        </ul>

    </nav>
```

CSS:
I designed my navigation bar to be displayed when the user press the "template" button
and hide it again by pressing the same button.

```
@media screen  and ( max-width : 675px){
.container{
    position: relative;
}
.menu-toggle{
    text-align: center;
    float: none;
    display: block;
    
}
.template{
    

    display: inline;
    float: right;
    padding: 0 40px;
    margin: auto;
    
}
li.table{
left: 80px;
height: 20px;
}
.nav{
    height: 90px;
}
.template:hover{
          display: inline;
    float: right;
    padding: 0 40px;  
    margin: auto;
}

.navigate,.active{
    text-align: center;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: auto;
    background-color: #b00000; 
    margin: 0;
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top:90px;
    transition: all 0.5 ease;
    left: 100%;
    
}

li.right{
    display: table;
    padding: 0;
    
    
}
.menu-toggle.bar{
    width: 25px;
    height: 3px;
    margin: 5px auto;
    transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.active{
     text-align: center;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: auto;
    background-color: #b00000; 
    margin: 0;
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top:90px;
    transition: all 0.5 ease;
    
}
```

}

JavaScript:
I brought the button "template" and "ul" by it ids

```
var template = document.getElementById('template');
var nav = document.getElementById('navigate');
template.onclick = function () {
        if (nav.className === ('navigate')) {

           nav.className += 'active';
        } else {
            nav.className = 'navigate';
        };
```

Comment: There is no `<button>`, and no element of any kind with id "template".

Comment: You're getting the 'template' button by ID, but it looks like you didn't set the id in your HTML. Also, multiple class names on the same element are separated by spaces, so change `nav.className += 'active'` to `nav.className += ' active'`.

Comment: In CSS selector syntax, multiple classes on the same elements are separated by a `.`, so you probably want to change `.navigate,.active` (which means, any element with the 'navigate' class OR any element with 'active' class) to this `.navigate.active` (which means any element that has 'navigate' AND 'active' classes simultaneously).

Comment: @pointy  I dont mean button , its a list designed as button   and the list with id "template" is in the third line of code              <li class="right table" id="table"><a class="list template" href="#template" >&#9776;</a></li>

Comment: Well your question clearly says "button".  And note the id on that line is "table", not "template".  Also, having an `<li>` element not in a `<ul>` or `<ol>` does not make sense anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `classList.toggle` method.

Also, to tidy up things, I've removed the list buttons, changed menu font color to white, and removed the duplicated CSS on classes `navigate` and `active`: now `.active` just displays the navigation menu.

(The navigation menu was exploding the width when opened, and it was clobbering the menu icon, so I just removed `position: absolute;` and `width: 100%` from it)

Far from done here. Try to change things in steps, and to study the css rules on MDN, instead of doing many things at once.

```js
var template = document.querySelector('.template');
var nav = document.querySelector('.navigate');

template.onclick = function() {
  nav.classList.toggle('active');
};
```

```css
  @media screen and ( max-width: 675px) {
  .container {
    position: relative;
  }
  .menu-toggle {
    text-align: center;
    float: none;
    display: block;
  }
  .template {
    display: inline;
    float: right;
    padding: 0 40px;
    margin: auto;
  }
  li.table {
    left: 80px;
    height: 20px;
  }
  .nav {
    height: 90px;
  }
  .template:hover {
    display: inline;
    float: right;
    padding: 0 40px;
    margin: auto;
  }
  .navigate {
    text-align: center;
    display: none;
    background-color: #b00000;
    list-style: none;  
    margin: 0;
    left: 0;
    top: 90px;
    transition: all 0.5 ease;
  }
  a.list:not(.template) {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
  }
  li.right {
    display: table;
    padding: 0;
  }
  .menu-toggle.bar {
    width: 25px;
    height: 3px;
    margin: 5px auto;
    transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    box-sizing: border-box;
  }
  .active {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: auto;
  }
```

```html
<div class="menu-toggle">
  <h1 id="logo">PROTOCOL</h1>
  <li class="right table" id="table"><a class="list template" href="#template">&#9776;</a></li>
  <span class="bar"></span>
  <span class="bar"></span>
  <span class="bar"></span>
</div>

<nav id="navigate">
  <ul class="navigate">
    <li><a class="list home" href="#home"> Home</a></li>
    <li><a class="list" href="#contacting">Contact us</a></li>
    <li class="right"><a class="list sign-up" href="#signing">Sign up</a></li>
    <li class="right"><a class="list" href="#logging">Log in</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

your code has many mistakes please create button having template class.
however i updated your javascript for current use

```
template.onclick = function () {
   if (nav.className === 'navigate') {

       nav.classList.remove('navigate')
       nav.className = 'active';
    }
   else {
        nav.classList.remove('active')
        nav.className = 'navigate';
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Checking the class name is fragile; if later some code adds more functionality that requires another class, this code will fail. The whole reason the `.classList` API was created was to avoid that sort of problem.

Comment: yes i knew that i just provided little fix to that code so he can understand